# Find out corresponding file extension given a filename in a folder

Tags: python, python-re

I want to implement such a function ： i input a filename without extension and a file list of a folder, then the program return the fullname with corresponding extension. For example, i input 'private_car_10', the file list of the folder is :

```
['private_car_1.png', 'private_car_10.jpg', 'private_car_100.jpeg', 'private_car_101.jpg', 'private_car_102.jpg', 'private_car_103.jpg', 'private_car_104.jpg', 'private_car_105.jpg', 'private_car_106.jpg', 'private_car_107.jpg', 'private_car_108.jpg', 'private_car_109.jpg', 'private_car_11.jpg', 'private_car_110.jpg', 'private_car_111.jpg', 'private_car_112.jpg', 'private_car_113.jpg', 'private_car_114.jpg', 'private_car_115.jpg', 'private_car_116.jpg', 'private_car_117.jpg', 'private_car_118.jpg', 'private_car_119.jpg', 'private_car_12.jpg', 'private_car_120.jpg', 'private_car_121.jpg', 'private_car_122.jpg', 'private_car_123.jpg', 'private_car_124.jpg', 'private_car_125.jpg', 'private_car_126.jpg', 'private_car_127.jpg', 'private_car_128.jpg', 'private_car_129.jpg', 'private_car_13.jpg', 'private_car_130.jpg', 'private_car_131.jpg', 'private_car_132.jpg', 'private_car_133.jpg', 'private_car_134.jpg', 'private_car_135.jpg', 'private_car_136.jpg', 'private_car_137.jpg', 'private_car_138.jpg', 'private_car_139.jpg', 'private_car_14.png', 'private_car_140.jpg', 'private_car_141.jpg', 'private_car_142.jpg', 'private_car_143.jpg', 'private_car_144.jpg', 'private_car_145.jpg', 'private_car_146.jpg', 'private_car_147.jpg', 'private_car_148.jpg', 'private_car_149.jpg', 'private_car_15.jpg', 'private_car_150.jpg', 'private_car_151.jpg', 'private_car_152.jpg', 'private_car_153.jpg', 'private_car_154.jpg', 'private_car_155.jpg', 'private_car_156.jpg', 'private_car_157.jpg', 'private_car_158.jpg', 'private_car_159.jpg', 'private_car_16.jpg', 'private_car_160.jpg', 'private_car_161.jpg', 'private_car_162.jpg', 'private_car_163.jpg', 'private_car_164.jpg', 'private_car_165.jpg', 'private_car_166.jpg', 'private_car_167.jpg', 'private_car_168.jpg', 'private_car_169.jpg', 'private_car_17.jpg', 'private_car_170.jpg', 'private_car_171.jpg', 'private_car_172.jpg', 'private_car_173.jpg', 'private_car_174.jpg', 'private_car_175.jpg', 'private_car_176.jpg', 'private_car_177.jpg', 'private_car_178.jpg', 'private_car_179.jpeg', 'private_car_18.jpg', 'private_car_180.jpg', 'private_car_181.jpg', 'private_car_182.jpg', 'private_car_183.jpg', 'private_car_184.jpg', 'private_car_185.jpg', 'private_car_186.jpg', 'private_car_187.jpg', 'private_car_188.jpg', 'private_car_189.jpg', 'private_car_19.jpg', 'private_car_190.jpg', 'private_car_191.jpg', 'private_car_192.jpg', 'private_car_193.jpg', 'private_car_194.jpg', 'private_car_195.jpg', 'private_car_196.jpg', 'private_car_197.png', 'private_car_198.jpg', 'private_car_199.jpg', 'private_car_2.jpg', 'private_car_20.jpg', 'private_car_200.jpg']
```

i expect the program return 'private_car_10.jpg'. I think i can using python re module, but i don't know to write the pattern.

Comment: Is it your intention that `'private_car_40'` is not in the list? And you want to have the file extension generated for based on similar filenames? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Actually the file list is very long, so i truncated to the first 200 elements, so in fact, there is private_car_40.jpg. I have updated the question description. Sorry again ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need regex here. Assuming that the filename must be in the list, you can simply split on the '.' and check if the filenames are equal.

```
def find_file_by_name(filename, folder_contents):
    return [file for file in folder_contents if file.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0] == filename]

filename = 'private_car_10'
folder = ['private_car_1.jpg', 'private_car_10.jpg', 'private_car_10.png', 'private_car_100.jpg', 'private_car_101.jpg', 'private_car_102.jpg', 'private_car_103.jpg', 'private_car_104.jpg', 'private_car_105.jpg', 'private_car_106.jpg', 'private_car_107.jpg', 'private_car_108.jpg', 'private_car_109.jpg', 'private_car_11.jpg', 'private_car_110.jpg', 'private_car_111.jpg', 'private_car_112.jpg', 'private_car_113.jpg', 'private_car_114.jpg', 'private_car_115.jpg', 'private_car_116.jpg', 'private_car_117.jpg', 'private_car_118.jpg', 'private_car_119.jpg', 'private_car_12.jpg', 'private_car_120.jpg', 'private_car_121.jpg', 'private_car_122.jpg', 'private_car_123.jpg', 'private_car_124.jpg', 'private_car_125.jpg', 'private_car_126.jpg', 'private_car_127.jpg', 'private_car_128.jpg', 'private_car_129.jpg', 'private_car_13.jpg', 'private_car_130.jpg', 'private_car_131.jpg', 'private_car_132.jpg', 'private_car_133.jpg', 'private_car_134.jpg', 'private_car_135.jpg', 'private_car_136.jpg', 'private_car_137.jpg', 'private_car_138.jpg', 'private_car_139.jpg', 'private_car_14.jpg', 'private_car_140.jpg', 'private_car_141.jpg', 'private_car_142.jpg', 'private_car_143.jpg', 'private_car_144.jpg', 'private_car_145.jpg', 'private_car_146.jpg', 'private_car_147.jpg', 'private_car_148.jpg', 'private_car_149.jpg', 'private_car_15.jpg', 'private_car_150.jpg', 'private_car_151.jpg', 'private_car_152.jpg', 'private_car_153.jpg', 'private_car_154.jpg', 'private_car_155.jpg', 'private_car_156.jpg', 'private_car_157.jpg', 'private_car_158.jpg', 'private_car_159.jpg', 'private_car_16.jpg', 'private_car_160.jpg', 'private_car_161.jpg', 'private_car_162.jpg', 'private_car_163.jpg', 'private_car_164.jpg', 'private_car_165.jpg', 'private_car_166.jpg', 'private_car_167.jpg', 'private_car_168.jpg', 'private_car_169.jpg', 'private_car_17.jpg', 'private_car_170.jpg', 'private_car_171.jpg', 'private_car_172.jpg', 'private_car_173.jpg', 'private_car_174.jpg', 'private_car_175.jpg', 'private_car_176.jpg', 'private_car_177.jpg', 'private_car_178.jpg', 'private_car_179.jpg', 'private_car_18.jpg', 'private_car_180.jpg', 'private_car_181.jpg', 'private_car_182.jpg', 'private_car_183.jpg', 'private_car_184.jpg', 'private_car_185.jpg', 'private_car_186.jpg', 'private_car_187.jpg', 'private_car_188.jpg', 'private_car_189.jpg', 'private_car_19.jpg', 'private_car_190.jpg', 'private_car_191.jpg', 'private_car_192.jpg', 'private_car_193.jpg', 'private_car_194.jpg', 'private_car_195.jpg', 'private_car_196.jpg', 'private_car_197.jpg', 'private_car_198.jpg', 'private_car_199.jpg', 'private_car_2.jpg', 'private_car_20.jpg', 'private_car_200.jpg']

res = find_file_by_name(filename, folder)
print(res)  # produces ['private_car_10.jpg', 'private_car_10.png']
```

What I do here is to traverse the list of files in your folder. I then split each file in the folder on the '.' substring which yields a sequence of [filename, extension] and if the filename matches the function input, I include the file in the list to return. I use rsplit and split once only so that filenames are allowed to contain '.' characters.

See the docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit

Comment: Sorry that i didn't say clearly that the extension is the folder not allways the same, there may be jpg, png, jpeg or else

Comment: @WadeWANG I updated my answer with a minimum working example. The function now produces a list of all matching filenames no matter the extension.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will break if the file name contains more than one period.

Comment: @LevB Nope, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to first convert your list into a dictionary.

```
import os
files = ['private_car_1.jpg', 'private_car_10.jpg', 'private_car_100.jpg', 'private_car_101.jpg', 'private_car_102.jpg', 'private_car_103.jpg'] 

di = {os.path.splitext(el)[0] : el for el in files}

print(di.get('private_car_100'))
```

Output:

```
private_car_100.jpg
```

Comment: This solution is neat, though it does create another dictionary. If the list is very long as stated by OP, this consumes more memory which the python vm will claim forever while running. However, I am not sure what OP's use case is. Just wanted to point that out. Here is a good read on python memory management: https://towardsdatascience.com/memory-management-in-python-6bea0c8aecc9

Comment: If memory is an issue, just delete the original list. No information is lost.

Comment: Python will still claim that memory in its vm indefinitely as long as it is running. I just wanted to point that out but we cannot be sure if that is an issue. Your solution is far more readable than mine. Have my upvote.